# Add my own custom keyboard to specific edit text

Tags: android, keyboard, android-input-method

I came to a big problem. I have my own custom keyboard. My goal is to use this keyboard in my other application.

First I tried to set this keyboard as a default device's keyboard programatically. I could do it through adb shell with no problem. But couldn't make it from app using Runtime.exec(). Unfortunately the device is not rooted.

I can use this keyboard when i enable it in settings and then set it as default input method, but I have to do it manually.

So now I would like to set this keyboard to all EditText's in my other application. Is this possible ? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this possible ?

No. The user gets to choose the input method editor, not you.

Comment: So the only way left is to create a keyboard as some layout with buttons being the keys. Then make it popup after focus on EditText, blocking popping of the default keyboard the same time ? Am I right ?

Comment: @10101101: That, or just allow the user the freedom to choose the keyboard that they want. Make sure that your approach will support users of all abilities, including the visually impaired, the motor-control impaired, different human languages, and so forth.

Comment: Thanks anyway for quick response friend!

Comment: I have an InputMethodService defined in my app. Is it possible to set it as the input method for an EditText in the same app?

Comment: @EhteshamHasan: No. Quoting my answer: "the user gets to choose the input method editor, not you". That includes any UI that happens to be in the same app as the input method editor.